# Is there exactly one Mobius transformation f such that f(4) = 3 and f(3) = 4?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Is there exactly one Mobius transformation $f$ such that $f(4) = 3$ and $f(3) = 4$?

Comment: If $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d},$ what can we say about the constants $a,b,c,d$ once we have $f(3) = 4$ and $f(4) = 3 \;?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Möbius transformations are triply transitive: there is a unique transformation taking a, b, c to A, B, C.  In general you should expect anything other than three points to three points to have infinitely-many possibilities.  In particular, you could have a transformation taking (3, 4, 0) to (4, 3, 1), or to (4, 3, 2), or to (4, 3, 3), ...

As Will Jagy points out in his comment, if $f(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$, $f(3) = 4$, and $f(4) = 3$, this gives you a system of equations:

$$
\frac{3a + b}{3c + d} = 4 \\
\frac{4a + b}{4c + d} = 3
$$

which becomes

$$
3a + b = 12c + 4d \\
4a + b = 12c + 3d
$$

or, as a homogeneous system,

$$
3a + b - 12c - 4d = 0 \\
4a + b - 12c - 3d = 0
$$

This system is solved by $a = -d$ and $b = 12c + 7d$; note $c$ and $d$ are free variables, so any choice of $c$ and $d$ will give you one of the infinitely-many possibilities.  (You also need to $ad - bc \neq 0$, but this is a non-linear condition, so it's probably easiest to plug in the above for $a$ and $b$ to get $-d^2 - 12c^2 - 7c \neq 0$ and then consider all the $(d, c)$ that don't satisfy this condition.  Intuitively "most" choices of $d$ and $c$ won't satisfy that quadratic equation.  More rigorously, this is some hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^2$ and so it has zero Lebesgue measure.)